# nestJs dto validate array has at least 2 entries

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I would like to validate that an array is present and has at least 1 entry. I am using @nestjs/class-validator.

The attribute products is not validated but the others are

```
export class CustomerOrderDto {
 ...
  @Type(() => Product)
  products: Product;
}

export class Product {
 @ValidateNested({ each: true })
 @IsArray()
 @ArrayNotEmpty()
 @ArrayMinSize(2)
 @IsString()
 artnr: string[];
}
```

The message passed in has:

```
{
  "currencyCode": "EUR",
 "products": ["test artnr"]}
```

Comment: try array min and max size so the length has to be exactly 2
```
    @IsArray()
    @ArrayNotEmpty()
    @ArrayMinSize(2)
    @ArrayMaxSize(2)
    products: Product[];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking for the request to throw an error as there are less than 2 entries in the array.  It also allows a message that does not have the products element , but correctly returns an error if currency is missing .